# Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'app'. Use 'app:name' to specify one

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a problem that is making me crazy. I have a [flask and python project](https://github.com/sasadangelo/calendar) that manages a vacation planner calendar for team and employee. So far I  only have Teams managed as CRUD application. The structure and code is similar to another project I have and that works fine.

However, if I run the following steps:

```
cd <workspace>
git clone https://github.com/sasadangelo/calendar
cd calendar
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
./run.sh
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'app'. Use 'app:name' to specify one.
```

I checked all possible articles (also on stackoverflow.com) but I was unable to solve the issue. The `run.sh` script is like this:

```
export FLASK_APP=app
flask run --debug
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but today I tried to rename my project in [benjamin](https://github.com/sasadangelo/benjamin). I thought there could be someconflict. with "calendar" name. Then I changed the `run.sh` file in:

```
export FLASK_APP=benjamin
flask run --debug
```

if anyone could explain the reason of this I will appreciate.